# Windows Authentication - Get windows username

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC4 application which uses Windows Authentication (WA), which is setup on Webconfig file as such:

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
  </system.web>
```

I am using this line of code to get the UserName, which in turn I am using in the LINQ Query shown:

```
var userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

var  loc  = (from l in data.Locations.OrderBy(l => l.LocationName)
                        join s in data.LocationSecurities.Where(s=> s.UserName.Contains(userName)) on l.LocationID equals s.LocationId
                        select new
                        {
                            LocationId = l.LocationID,
                            Name = l.LocationName
                        }
                        ).ToList().Distinct();
```

This works in debug mode, however it doesn't when the Application is published to the localhost or the Webserver. I have looked at SQL Profiler. It seems to be taking the username as the **DefaultAppPool**, which is not bringing back any results!

This is the profiler trace:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[LocationID] AS [LocationID], 
[Extent1].[LocationName] AS [LocationName]
FROM  [admin].[Location] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [admin].[LocationSecurity] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[LocationID] = [Extent2].[LocationID]
WHERE [Extent2].[UserName] LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE N''~''',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'%DefaultAppPool%'
```

Any idea on why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It happens because in debugging mode, the process is ran by your user identity. When you publish it to the IIS, another user identity is used to run the process so it does not work.

Comment: As per Dave Bish's answer below, I don't think you need that much code to find the user you require. There's some 'shortcut' options within MVC/System.Web

Answer (score 4):

To get the currently logged-in user from within an action method (Via Windows auth) you have to query the current HttpContext, with something like:

```
HttpContext.User.Identity.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Code in your web.config:

```
 <authentication mode="Windows">
         </authentication>
```

.Code in page:

```
Response.Write(Page.User.Identity.Name);
```

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`.  You retrieve the user's currently logged-in name via the current `HttpContext`.

Comment: Providing one line and code-only "answers" are rarely (if ever) deemed acceptable on SO. Please try to provide some explanation as to why your answer should work.